# Does ActiveMerchant support PayPal Digital Goods for Express Checkout transactions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I know ActiveMerchant supports the standard Express Checkout API, but the Digital Goods integration document describes several EC features *not* supported by the Digital Goods Express Checkout API. It appears at least one of those features (Authorization & Capture) is used by ActiveMerchant. Is it possible to use ActiveMerchant for PayPal micropayments?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to, yes. The only difference between Express Checkout and Express Checkout for Digital Goods is the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital switch, which identifies it as a Digital Goods transaction.
Of course, you'll need to handle the JS include to initiate the flow as well, but other than that it's pretty much the same beast.

Comment: Thanks! How does one set that switch in activemerchant?  I can't seem to figure that out.